# C++ - Calculating the inverse of a matrix

Tags: c++, math

I've tried to write a program that should be able to calculate the inverse of a matrix:
Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>

double getDeterminant(const std::vector<std::vector<double>> vect) {
    if(vect.size() != vect[0].size()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Matrix is not quadratic");
    } 
    int dimension = vect.size();

    if(dimension == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    if(dimension == 1) {
        return vect[0][0];
    }

    //Formula for 2x2-matrix
    if(dimension == 2) {
        return vect[0][0] * vect[1][1] - vect[0][1] * vect[1][0];
    }

    double result = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++) {

        //Submatrix
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> subVect(dimension - 1, std::vector<double> (dimension - 1));
        for(int m = 1; m < dimension; m++) {
            int z = 0;
            for(int n = 0; n < dimension; n++) {
                if(n != i) {
                    subVect[m-1][z] = vect[m][n];
                    z++;
                }
            }
        }

        //recursive call
        result = result + sign * vect[0][i] * getDeterminant(subVect);
        sign = -sign;
    }

    return result;
}

std::vector<std::vector<double>> getTranspose(const std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix1) {

    //Transpose-matrix: height = width(matrix), width = height(matrix)
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> solution(matrix1[0].size(), std::vector<double> (matrix1.size()));

    //Filling solution-matrix
    for(size_t i = 0; i < matrix1.size(); i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < matrix1[0].size(); j++) {
            solution[j][i] = matrix1[i][j];
        }
    }
    return solution;
}

std::vector<std::vector<double>> getCofactor(const std::vector<std::vector<double>> vect) {
    if(vect.size() != vect[0].size()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Matrix is not quadratic");
    } 

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> solution(vect.size(), std::vector<double> (vect.size()));
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> subVect(vect.size() - 1, std::vector<double> (vect.size() - 1));

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < vect[0].size(); j++) {

            int p = 0;
            for(size_t x = 0; x < vect.size(); x++) {
                if(x == i) {
                    continue;
                }
                int q = 0;

                for(size_t y = 0; y < vect.size(); y++) {
                    if(y == j) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    subVect[p][q] = vect[x][y];
                    q++;
                }
                p++;
            }
            solution[i][j] = pow(-1, i + j) * getDeterminant(subVect);
        }
    }
    return solution;
}

std::vector<std::vector<double>> getInverse(const std::vector<std::vector<double>> vect) {
    if(getDeterminant(vect) == 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Determinant is 0");
    } 
    double d = 1.0/getDeterminant(vect);
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> solution(vect.size(), std::vector<double> (vect.size()));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < vect.size(); j++) {
            solution[i][j] = vect[i][j] * d; 
        }
    }

    return getTranspose(getCofactor(solution));
}

void printMatrix(const std::vector<std::vector<double>> vect) {
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
        for(std::size_t j = 0; j < vect[0].size(); j++) {
            std::cout << std::setw(8) << vect[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix(3, std::vector<double> (3));
    matrix = {
        {1,2,3},
        {4,5,6},
        {7,8,8}
    };

    printMatrix(getInverse(matrix));
    return 0;
}
```

The functions for calculating the determinant, the transpose- and the cofactor-matrix work correctly (as far as I can see), but the function for calculating the inverse-matrix doesn't.
I searched the internet and found [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/405128/Matrix-Operations-in-Java), which uses the same function for calculating the inverse.

Is this formula incorrect, or do you have any other idea, why it doesnt work?

---

The matrix I am using is

[image]

and the inverse of it should be

[image]

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code using a debugger while it is executing? That is generally a good way to narrow down the specific issue. In this case pass a small matrix that you could invert by hand (pen and paper) and see if your code is tracking the same calculations.

Comment: The formula seems to be partially correct as it works for a few example matrices such as `[[1,2],[3,4]]`. You must have some subtler bug in there. You need to go through it step-by-step and see where the incorrect numbers start appearing for the first time.

Comment: I don't remember how to calculate inverse matrix (general formula for all kinds). Maybe on https://math.stackexchange.com/ you could find someone who would be expert on matrix to help you with the algorithm.

Comment: Aside: if you are going to use `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` for a matrix, you should probably check every inner vector is the same size as the outer. `if(std::any_of(vect.begin(), vect.end(),[size = vect.size()](auto & inner){ return inner.size() != size; })) { throw ... }` It will also remove the undefined behaviour of the `dimension == 0` case.

Comment: You may not come back and read comments, but most systems do not calculate the inverse of a matrix this way.  A more common method is LU decomposition with pivoting.    There's a great book called "Numerical Recipes in C" that provide a great write up and code.

Comment: Also note that the algorithm you implemented is really slow because you have to compute all these sub-determinants. I think it scales as O(n!). A better approach would be to use the Gauss algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination, which works in (O(n^3)) time complexity. Still nice code though.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, thanks for your comments.

The problem was the order of execution.
The correct solution is:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> getInverse(const std::vector<std::vector<double>> vect) {
    if(getDeterminant(vect) == 0) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Determinant is 0");
    } 

    double d = 1.0/getDeterminant(vect);
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> solution(vect.size(), std::vector<double> (vect.size()));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < vect.size(); j++) {
            solution[i][j] = vect[i][j]; 
        }
    }

    solution = getTranspose(getCofactor(solution));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < vect.size(); j++) {
            solution[i][j] *= d;
        }
    }

    return solution;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but your code does not work when the input matrix's dimension is 1. Here is a workaround that I used:

```
vector<vector<double>> inverse(const vector<vector<double>> A) {
    double d = 1.0/det(A);
    vector<vector<double>> solution(A.size(), vector<double> (A.size()));

    if(A.size() == 1){
        vector<double> ans = {0};
        ans[0] = 1.0/det(A);
        solution[0] = ans;
        return solution;
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < A.size(); j++) {
            solution[i][j] = A[i][j] * d; 
        }
    }

    return transpose(cofactor(solution));
}
```